# Is $\phi^T_tP_t^{-1}\phi_t\to 0$ when $P_{t+1}=\sum_{k=0}^t\phi_k\phi_k^T+P_0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence

Let $\phi_t\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\forall t\geq0$, and $\sup_t\|\phi_t\|_2^2\leq M<\infty$(euclidean norm). Define $n\times n$ positive definitive matrices as follow,
$$P_{t+1}=\sum_{k=0}^t\phi_k\phi_k^T+P_0,\forall t\geq0, $$
where $P_0$ is a positive definitive matrix.

Is it suffices to show that $\phi_t^TP_t^{-1}\phi_t\to 0$?

I have tried in this way: Since $\phi_t^TP_t^{-1}\phi_t\leq \lambda_{max}(P_t^{-1})\|\phi_t\|_2^2$, if $\lambda_{max}(P_t^{-1})\to 0$, we can obtain the conclusion. 
However, a counterexample is $\phi_t=[1\;0]^T$, $\forall t$, and $P_0=I_{2\times2}$, then 
$$P_t=\begin{bmatrix}
    t+2 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
  \end{bmatrix},
$$
and $\phi_t^TP_t^{-1}\phi_t\to 0$ but $\lambda_{max}(P_t^{-1})=1$, $\forall t$.